# updating in a query with joins. Counter to be increased by number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a following query.

```
UPDATE 
tbl_bookings tb
INNER JOIN
tbl_slots ts
ON ( tb.slot_id = ts.id )
SET tb.seat_freed = 1, ts.free_machines = ts.free_machines + 1
WHERE 1
AND tb.seat_freed = 0
AND tb.transactionComplete = 0
```

Here I am trying to free the seats by updating the `seat_freed` to 1 and increasing the `free_machines` counter by 1.

In case, there are more than 1 rows (say 3 rows) returned from `tbl_bookings`, I would want to increment the counter by .

Is there any way to do it, using the single. I can obviously do it by breaking it down into different queries, but single query is what I desire. :)

Comment: So you want to increase your counter if there has been more than one row affected by the update?

Comment: Yes, For eg. say that `tb.seat_freed` = 1 was done for 3 rows, then `ts.free_machines` should be increased by 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery with the exact same conditions to calculat the number of rows which will be affected by the update. I used DISTINCT for the count since i don't know how bookings and slots are related in your example.

```
UPDATE tbl_bookings tb
    INNER JOIN tbl_slots ts ON ( tb.slot_id = ts.id )
    INNER JOIN (SELECT count(DISTINCT b.id) seats_to_be_freed 
                FROM tbl_bookings b INNER JOIN tbl_slots s ON ( b.slot_id = s.id ) 
                WHERE b.seat_freed=0 and b.transactionComplete=0) tmp
SET tb.seat_freed = 1, ts.free_machines = tmp.seats_to_be_freed 
WHERE 1
    AND tb.seat_freed = 0
    AND tb.transactionComplete = 0
```

Comment: I agree that something like this would work.. But as I said, I am expecting a single.. i.e. without any subqueries.. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: ok, i understood that you want a single statement. I'm pretty sure that what you expect is not possible.

Comment: thats what I think.. But who knows.. Lets see if someone comes up with a better answer.. :D